# SQL Combine 2 Tables without a primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have just started learning sql and I am trying to understand how I can do the following in SQL.

I have 2 tables:
Example - TableA (Id), TableB(Id, Text)

```
Following are the values in Table A:
1
2
1
```

Following are the values in Table B (Note - the text column will always have a similar value with the ID it has):

```
1, Tom
2, John
1, Tom
3, Doe
```

I tried doing the following query:
"Select TableB.Text from TableB, TableA where TableA.Id = TableB.Id"

And it returned:

```
Tom
Tom
John
Tom
Tom
```

Where I am looking for:

```
Tom
John
Tom
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction if this is possible in SQL?

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I am using the following version - v3.20.1

Comment: Are you sure? 3.20 was released more than twenty years ago. Where did you see this number?

Comment: Yes I am just trying to learn this so I was on an online SQL editor - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php

Comment: But this is SQLite, not MySQL. While there are a lot similarities, they are still way different!

Comment: I also tried the same example on W3 SQL, so I am just trying to understand is there a way to write a query to solve this?

Comment: As you start learning, here are two advice: **1)** You are using a join syntax that was made redundant more than 25 years ago. It should no longer be used. Whichever tutorial or teacher taught you this: dismiss them. You should use explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, …) instead. **2)** Tables are unsorted data sets. 1,2,1 is the same as 2,1,1 etc. Your tables don't make much sense anyway. Start with tables that do, to get a feeling how tables are designed and how queries actually work. A typical teaching database has students, teachers, and classes or departments and employees.

Comment: As to the query: You get this result, because the two ones in table A relate to both ones in table B, so you get four joined pairs 1-1, 1-1, 1-1, 1-1. Well and the two in table A is of course paired with the two in table B, so you also get 2-2. Five records all in all which you get in arbitrary order, because you specified no `ORDER BY` clause in your query. You could just as well have ended up with Tom,Tom,Tom,John,Tom for instance. As mentioned: learn with realistic tables in order to learn properly.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner, no one taught me. This was my 2nd day in trying to self teach myself SQL and understand different concepts in it! I appreciate your thoughts and explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining `tableb` directly you can "distinctify" it first in a subquery.

```
SELECT b.text
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    id,
                    text
                    FROM tableb) b
            INNER JOIN tablea a
                       ON a.id = b.id;
```

The distinct version of `tableb` looks like:

```
id   text
---------
1    Tom
2    John
3    Doe
```

The second `'Tom'` is gone. Like that there aren't two rows matching ID `1` anymore, which caused the `'Tom'`s to be two times in the result of your original query for every row with ID `1` from `tablea`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!